# Problem of recovery of an element selected in a select

Tags: php, sql, laravel-8

I am a beginner in Laravel. I want to implement a feature that:

I want to use Laravel 8 and PHP:

1. Select a part of the data in a table (via a select)

   - how to get the id selected in the select :
     -> get the identifier selected in the option tag in order to use it in an sql query that combines selection and insertion
2. Copy the data and insert it in another table (via an add button)

   - how to recover the id present in the url of the page
3. Display the data inserted in a table

   - no problem

```
<select name="id_segment" class="form-control">

<?php
$req1 = DB::select("SELECT id_segment, nom_segment FROM `segements` ");
foreach ($req1 as $re1 => $r1) {
 ?>
                            <option name="id_segment" value="{{ $r1->id_segment }}"> {{ $r1->id_segment }}
                                {{ $r1->nom_segment }}</option>
                            <?php
 } ?>
                        </select>

                    </div>
                </div>


                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12 text-center">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="AjoutSegment">Ajouter</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" href="{{ route('groupecampagnes.index') }}"> Back</a>
                </div>
```

I have already tried with $_POST and $_GET while making a var_dump, but I have seen that some people say that it does not work, me it gave me the display of an error with the id that I seek to recover precisely, whereas it should just display it to me on the page to see if I recover it well and truly. The var_dump is not present in the code because I removed it in the meantime. After I tried various solutions found on the net, which have me display as error for some of them that I had to do with a std class object.

Comment: Please read the [markdown guide](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and fix your question, it is borderline unreadable in its current state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code is in a file called page and stored in the views directory (resources/views/page.blade.php), you could go to your controller and pass the needed data to your view like this:

```
$segments = DB::select("SELECT id_segment, nom_segment FROM `segements` ")->get();

return view('page', compact('segments'))
```

Then you can use it in your view:

```
<select name="id_segment" class="form-control">
    @foreach ($segments as $r1)
        <option name="id_segment" value="{{ $r1->id_segment }}"> {{ $r1->id_segment }} {{ $r1->nom_segment }}</option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, I will test it right away and I will tell you if it worked. Besides, I have been stuck on this problem for 2 weeks.

Comment: I thank you again for your answer, but the part about the controller, it considers that there is an error on the sql request while the class is present. But in fact I'm trying to get the id selected in the option tag just to use it in an sql query that combines selection and insertion. I just can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Thank you for your help, but now I have solved my problem, again thank you for taking the time to help me.